# Solving the quadratic equation $a X^2 + a Y^2 + 2 b X + 2 c Y + d = 0$.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I'm trying to solve the following quadratic equation, but I have no idea how:
$$a X^2 + a Y^2 + 2 b X + 2 c Y + d = 0,$$
where the coefficients are real numbers. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: Try to recast this into an equation of a circle.

Comment: Well, I am a teen and have no idea of how I can solve it, but if you provide me with a second equation that can help.

Comment: For which variable are you trying to solve?

Comment: If $a\neq 0$, this is an equation for a circle.  Whether this circle exists in the real space depends on whether $b^2+c^2>4ad$, $b^2+c^2=4ad$, or $b^2+c^2<4ad$.  $$\ $$ If $a=0$ but $b\neq 0$ or $c\neq 0$, this is an equation of a line.  $$\ $$ If $a=b=c=0$, this is an equation $d=0$, which is true or false depending on whether $d=0$.

Comment: Yup.... that's what we have to ask... But probably he's searching  for an X and a Y.

Comment: Yo ! So there comes a nice answer.

Comment: I would like to fix my comment above.  I should have said: $$\text{Whether this circle exists in the real space depends on}\\\text{whether $b^2+c^2>ad$, $b^2+c^2=ad$, or $b^2+c^2<ad$.}$$  (I forgot that the coefficients of the $X$- and $Y$-terms were ${\color{red}2}b$ and ${\color{red}2}c$, not just $b$ and $c$.)

Comment: What do you think you mean by "solve"? People are assuming that you mean you want to find values of X and Y for which the equation is true, but maybe you don't mean that? Maybe you just want to re-arrange this into a circle or other conic?

Comment: Divide through by $a$ and complete the squares in $X$ and $Y$ to get an equation in standard form.

Comment: @Paul Actually I want to sketch the set of solutions.

Comment: @g.pomegranate Assuming $b^2+c^2\ge d$, make a circle, and you are done.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Find solutions of $ax^2+ay^2+2bx+2cy+d=0$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$.

**Meant to be a comment**

Assuming $b^2+c^2\ge d, a\neq 0$, you can always choose $a>0$ and then

\begin{align*}
\left(x+\frac ba\right)^2+\left(y+\frac ca\right)^2&=r^2\\
x^2+y^2+\frac {2b}{a}x+\frac {2c}{a}y+\frac {b^2+c^2}{a^2}&=r^2\\
ax^2+ay^2+2bx+2cy+\underbrace{(b^2+c^2-ar^2)}_{d}&=0\\
\end{align*}
is a *real* circle with center $\left(-\frac ba,-\frac ca\right)$ and $r=\frac{\sqrt{b^2+c^2-d}}a$.